# C# .net 4.8 Razor: Copy files from local Disk to Azure Blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am still struggling with the following problem that is driving me crazy.
I am trying to copy files from my C# webapp from the local disk to an Azure blob storage. When I run the program from Azure, the program tries to copy the file from the server disk and not from the local client disk where it was previously selected from the web page.
Finding this has been quite a pain in the ass for me, as no error message .... until now.
In the code example you can see what I am trying to do.

Normally the file should be available via the HttpPostedFileBase. By the way "ActionResult Upload(..." doesn't work for me either, it only works via "ActionResult Index(..." for whatever reason.

Has anyone done this before and can tell me what I'm doing wrong? Please do not write in riddles, I need an exact answer with code example if possible.
Thanks in advance to whoever helps me.

To test, I have already reduced the function to the absolutely necessary.

```
**Razor html** ---------------------------------------
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" />
   <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>

**cSharp** -------------------------------------------
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

//other code ......
   
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) //IFormFile ?
{
    string containerName = "fileupload";
    string connectionString = Def...=https;A..Name=st..e;A..Key=....Z==;End..x=core.windows.net";

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0];
        var newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH-mm-ss") + "_" + myCountry + "_" + file.FileName;
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
        BlobClient blobClientF = containerClient.GetBlobClient(newFileName);
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        blobClientF.UploadAsync(filestream, true);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and can able to upload files to my storage account container with C# webapp.

**Code:**

**Program.cs:**

```c
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "upload",
    pattern: "Home/UploadFile",
    defaults: new { controlle = "home", action = "uploadFile" });

app.Run();
```

**Controllers/HomeController.cs:**

```c
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication8.Models;

namespace WebApplication8.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
            {
                string containerName = "kamcontainer"; 
                string connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureStorage");

                var newFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HH-mm-ss") + "_" + file.FileName;
                BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
                BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

                BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(newFileName);
                using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
                {
                    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        // Handle errors and display a user-friendly error page when an exception occurs
        // ResponseCache with explicit values
    

> [ResponseCache (Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
> NoStore = true)]

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

ResponseCache Location and Duration [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-7.0#location-and-duration)

**Views/Home/index.cshtml:**

```c
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**appsettings.json:**

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureStorage": "<storage_account_connec_string>"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Project structure:**

[image]

**Output:**

It runs successfully as below,

[image]

And it opens in the browser as below then I click on the **Choose File** option to choose a file that I want to upload as a blob,

[image]

I chose a file and click on **Upload File** as below,

[image]

***Then, the file uploaded as a blob to my storage account container in Azure Portal as below,***

I have uploaded three files to the container as below,

[image]